# Can we generate QR code through Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, qr-code

I am developing an Android app in xamarin in which I require to create a QR code from the data input by the user in various fields.

SO my question is can I do it with the help of Xamarin? If yes then please help me with any sample code or tutorial link.

Answer (score 11):

[ZXing.Net](https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile) has a QR code generator built in. Take a look at that.

Something like this could do the job (following code not tested):

```
var writer = new BarcodeWriter
{
    Format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,
    Options = new EncodingOptions
                {
                    Height = 200,
                    Width = 600
                }
};
var bitmap = writer.Write("My content");
```

This should generate an image with the QR code. There are loads of other options you can mess with.

ZXing is also available as a [component for Xamarin.Android, Xamarin.iOS and Windows Phone](http://components.xamarin.com/view/zxing.net.mobile)